# Merge to sets of data and replace current value if is in update column

Tags: r, replace, merge

With the following data frames. I would like to create a new data frame where quantities for IDs in df2 are updated with the 'Update quantities' values and IDs are replaces with the 'Update_ID' values (which may or may not change from the current ID.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:10],Quantity = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
df2 <- data.frame(Cur_ID = c("A","C","D","H"), Update_ID = c("A","C","X","Y"), Update_Quantity = c(20, 21, 22, 23))

desired df3:
ID  letters
A   20
B   2
C   21
X   22
E   5
F   6
G   7
Y   23
I   9
J   10
```

i.e. the quantities for all in df2 are updates, and the IDs if Update_ID is different from Cur_ID.

Answer (score 4):

With `dplyr`, you could merge `df2` into `df1` and use `coalesce()` to update `ID` and `Quantity`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("ID" = "Cur_ID")) %>%
  mutate(ID = coalesce(Update_ID, ID),
         Quantity = coalesce(Update_Quantity, Quantity), .keep = "unused")
```

---

Another option with `powerjoin`:

```r
library(powerjoin)

power_left_join(df1, setNames(df2, c("Cur_ID", "ID", "Quantity")),
                by = c("ID" = "Cur_ID"), conflict = coalesce_yx)
```

###### Output

```
#    ID Quantity
# 1   A       20
# 2   B        2
# 3   C       21
# 4   X       22
# 5   E        5
# 6   F        6
# 7   G        7
# 8   Y       23
# 9   I        9
# 10  J       10
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table` join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, c('ID', 'Quantity') := .(Update_ID, 
         Update_Quantity), on = .(ID = Cur_ID)]
```

-output

```
> df1
        ID Quantity
    <char>    <num>
 1:      A       20
 2:      B        2
 3:      C       21
 4:      X       22
 5:      E        5
 6:      F        6
 7:      G        7
 8:      Y       23
 9:      I        9
10:      J       10
```

Comment: Thanks, i have got this solution working for my data. 1 additional question i have, is could this be adjusted to deal with instances where an ID is in df2 but not in df1 and does get included in the new df.
e.g. if df2 were: df2 <- data.frame(Cur_ID = c("A","C","D","H","M"), Update_ID = c("A","C","X","Y","M"), Update_Quantity = c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24))
And ID=M is included in the new df?

Answer (score 1):

With a base R approach:

```r
type.convert(         
  data.frame(
    t(with(df2, apply(df1, 1, \(x) {
      if (x[1] %in% Cur_ID)
      {
        y <- x[1];
        x[1] <- Update_ID[Cur_ID == x[1]]; 
        x[2] <- Update_Quantity[Cur_ID == y]
      }
      x
    })))), 
  as.is = T
)

#>    ID Quantity
#> 1   A       20
#> 2   B        2
#> 3   C       21
#> 4   X       22
#> 5   E        5
#> 6   F        6
#> 7   G        7
#> 8   Y       23
#> 9   I        9
#> 10  J       10
```